# Modal Popup postback in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

How to prevent an aspx page in an iframe causing a postback

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour  The controls in the Page are causing a postback..almost every control cause a postback.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by 
a. assigning a button as panel default and via button property

or b. with jquery

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="Button1" />
Button1.UseSubmitBehavior="False"
```

with jquery

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```